# mod_rewrite issues after Apache 2.4 upgrade

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, centos, http-status-code-404

I have been lurking on here for many years and love StackOverflow to death. This is actually the first time I haven't been able to find a solution and it is driving me insane.

A client of mine has had a site running CentOS 5.11 with Apache 2.2.3 and PHP 5.5.13 for a while.  We have kinda been forced to migrate to a new server running CentOS 7.3.1611 with Apache 2.4.6 and PHP 5.5.38.

I have made sure that my mod_rewrite module is loading and set the AllowOverride All for  in httpd.conf.  The site is running the Twig templating engine which relies on the .htaccess to direct things back to be handled by the index.  My original .htaccess simply had this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This had been working with no issues but after migrating the site refuses to function.  I am getting 500 and 404 errors all over the place.  I have a /directory/item call that breaks because there is a directory.html file that matches which I don't understand. Tells me directory.html/item.html does not exist. In my images directory there is an .htaccess that simply has "Options +Indexes" in it... when I remove that some of the 404 errors get resolved. I was able to get the proper directory page to load by doing "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html !-f" but that winds up breaking stuff again!! Does anyone here have any ideas that might help me shed some light on this?

Comment: It seems apache is automatically appending your filenames with .html. You might have MultiViews enabled. Try `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: It was 'Options -Indexes -MultiViews'  I tried changing it to just 'Options -MultiViews' and commenting it out altogether.  Nothing changed... a request to http://example.com/directory/item/ returns the error The requested URL /directory.html/item/ was not found on this server.  When I delete the directory.html file in the main folder it works... how do I get it to ignore directory.html?  It worked fine on the old server.

Comment: Do you have mod_negotiation enabled in apache? If so try disabling it.

Comment: Omg Thakkie I want to give you a huge virtual kiss... that was what was causing it!!  I can't believe I didn't find anyone else suggesting it.  What exactly is that module and what am I risking by disabling it?

I still have the issue with the other .htaccess file containing the

    Options +Indexes

When I try to view any image in that folder I get an internal server error... goes away when removed but I am hesitant as I don't know what function it serves.

Comment: I am not really sure why anyone would use it, but you can find the [documetation here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_negotiation.html)

Comment: Hmm ... after reading the documentation I still see no reason why it would cause the .html to be injected like that.  Strange ... I would like to know what is happening behind the scenes there.  Thank you so much @Thakkie you helped me immensely... I am not sure I would ever have found that.